# OS reinstall backup

Tags: backup

I'm interested in fully re-installing my Ubuntu 22.04 operating system (specifically Kubuntu, but it shouldn't matter.) I would like to re-install without losing any data/files/configurations and was interested in how I should do that. Should I copy my /home directory to an external hard drive and then copy it back to the fresh reinstall? Or should I back up my entire / directory? Thanks.

Comment: The Backups app is installed in Ubuntu by default.  It will back up your entire /home directory and should be used as part of your standard best practices methodology.

Comment: I suggest you read my answer in this post I just marked this as a duplicate of; I have some installs I *~weekly* re-install on instead of applying patches in the conventional way as it both upgrades the packages (*as I use a daily ISO which includes updated packages*) at the same time as ensuring our ISOs work  as expected (ie. an *Quality Assurance* test is performed).  FYI:  I find the *flavors* easier in this case; as *universe* is always enabled with *flavors*.  Yes you **should backup all data first** as its easy to make a mistake.

Comment: Another FYI:  I'm on my current *primary* PC now, and had an issue that was *irking* me back in late-August.. As I wasn't *fixing* it fast enough; I resorted to a non-destructive re-install using the current *daily (20230829) & just re-installed; meaning in <15 minutes the system was back functional (*though I spent another ~30 mins checking it out*).  Me; I only took a list of what packages I had installed (text list) & ensured my copy of my user directory (`/home/$USER`) was backed up, as from that I know I have everything needed for me to re-create my box.

Comment: On my actual system, my fonts are *system wide installed* (*so available for all users & not in my $HOME so weren't backed up*), but that didn't worry me as I have some scripts that will re-install those for any new installs...  ie. what you need to backup is specific with how you use your box (*eg. I prefer system wide font installs to user-based installs, so my backup would have required some system directories if that data couldn't easily be re-created which I knew it could; I'm using fonts as example here as it applies elsewhere too*).

Comment: An implied premise of the question is that you don't know where all of your data/files/configurations are located. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to re-discover custom files in /etc and other places outside /home. As the human, it's your task to keep track of each customization you make, document them (you will forget!), and add them to your backup/restore method. Experienced users often rely upon standard locations and documentation (keeping notes) to keep track of their data and customizations.